# Arrows along a partial named path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path, curve-fitting

I am trying to reproduce following image:

[image]

For that I create 3 nodes, a support path (`mycurve`) and (hidden) support lines (`l1` to `l12`) then place other nodes on the `lx` and `mycurve` intersections. This works well.

I am trying to setup the arrows. The support lines for the arrows are just a translation of `mycurve`. I use a smooth plot to draw the arrows but the result is not perfect especially for arrows that do not have intermediate drawing points (such as from 7 to 8).

Is there a way to use the previously drawn support curves instead of using a plot to draw the arrows?
In other words, I would like to draw a path from `5.x` to `8.x` along named path `mycurve3` instead of using a plot (and same for the others).

Thanks in advance.

Here is my result:

[image]

And the source for my MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\tikzset{
  degree/.style = {
    circle,
    draw,
    fill=white,
  },
  l/.style = {
    -latex,
    line width = #1,
  },
  l1/.style = { l=1pt },
  l2/.style = { l=2pt },
  l3/.style = { l=3pt },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,
    yscale=1]

  \pgfdeclarelayer{nodes}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{links}
  \pgfsetlayers{main,links,nodes}


  \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
    %% Create on each degree to intersect later with mycurve.
    %% Each line is a named path from l1 to l12
    \foreach \i in {1,...,12}{
      \coordinate[] (l1-\i) at (0,\i/1.5);
      \coordinate[] (l2-\i) at (3.5,\i/1.5);
      \path[name path global=l\i] (l1-\i) -- (l2-\i);
    }
  \end{pgfonlayer}


  \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodes}
    \node[degree] (1) at (0,    0/1.5) {1};
    \node[degree] (5) at (2,    7/1.5) {5};
    \node[degree] (8) at (0,   12/1.5) {8};
  \end{pgfonlayer}


  \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
    \draw [line width=5pt,red!20,name path global=mycurve]
    ($ (8) + (0.0,0) $) to[out=-30,in=90]
    ($ (5) + (0.0,0) $) to[in=57,out=-90]
    ($ (1) + (0.0,0) $);

    %% Create an intersection coordinate for each l1-l12 lines and mycurve
    %% to place each degree. Each intersection point is named i1 to i12.
    \def\mycurveIntersection#1{%
      \path[name intersections={of=l#1 and mycurve}] (intersection-1) coordinate (i#1);
    }
    \foreach \i in {1,...,12}{
      \mycurveIntersection\i
      %%\fill[red] (i\i) circle (2pt);
    }
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodes}
    \node[degree] (2) at (i2) {2};
    \node[degree] (3) at (i4) {3};
    \node[degree] (4) at (i5) {4};
    \node[degree] (6) at (i9) {6};
    \node[degree] (7) at (i11) {11};

    %% Draw to arrows supports lines
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
      \draw [red,name path global=mycurve\i]
      ($ (8) + (4-\i,0) $) to[out=-30,in=90]
      ($ (5) + (4-\i,0) $) to[in=57,out=-90]
      ($ (1) + (4-\i,0) $);
    }

  \end{pgfonlayer}


  %% Draw the links
  %%
  %% TODO: find a better way using previously created mycurves 1-3.
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{links}
    \def\myshift{3}
    \draw[l1,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (i7) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i8) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i9) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i10) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i11) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i12) + (\myshift,0) $)};
    \draw[l1,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (i7) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i6) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i5) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i4) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i3) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i2) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i1) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (1) + (\myshift,0) $)
    };

    \def\myshift{2}
    \draw[l2,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (6) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i10) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i11) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (8) + (\myshift,0) $)};
    \draw[l2,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (6) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i8) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (5) + (\myshift,0) $)};
    \draw[l2,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (3) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i3) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (2) + (\myshift,0) $)};

    \def\myshift{1}
    \draw[l3] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (2) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i1) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (1) + (\myshift,0) $)
    };
    %% These ones are really not on the mycurves
    \draw[l3] ($ (7) + (\myshift,0)$) -- ($ (8) + (\myshift,0)$);
    \draw[l3] ($ (4) + (\myshift,0)$) -- ($ (3) + (\myshift,0)$);

  \end{pgfonlayer}

  %% Add extra line helpers for reading
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
    \draw[dashed] (1) -- (8);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i7) + (3,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i7)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i9) + (2,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i9)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i4) + (2,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i4)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i5) + (1,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i5)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i2) + (1,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i2)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i11) + (1,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i11)!(8) $);
  \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the result is quite acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer because it would require some feedback. The main message is that:

> Yes, there is a means to redraw intersection segments of arbitrary paths.

This can be accomplished with the `fillbetween` library of `pgfplots` (!). Applied to the paths you are not happy with, using these one obtains

[image]

This is the code, where they are drawn with commands of the type

```
 \RedrawSegment[l3]{3}{5}{4}
```

in which the optional argument is the line style, the firs one the level and the other two the lines which you want to compute the intersections with.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} % ,bending would look better but clashes with the way you
% construct your paths
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\tikzset{
  degree/.style = {
    circle,
    draw,
    fill=white,
  },
  l/.style = {
    -latex,
    line width = #1,
  },
  l1/.style = { l=1pt },
  l2/.style = { l=2pt },
  l3/.style = { l=3pt },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1,
    yscale=1]

  \pgfdeclarelayer{nodes}
  \pgfdeclarelayer{links}
  \pgfsetlayers{main,links,nodes}


  \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
    %% Create on each degree to intersect later with mycurve.
    %% Each line is a named path from l1 to l12
    \foreach \i in {1,...,12}{
      \coordinate[] (l1-\i) at (0,\i/1.5);
      \coordinate[overlay] (l2-\i) at (10,\i/1.5);
      \path[overlay,name path global=l\i] (l1-\i) -- (l2-\i);
    }
  \end{pgfonlayer}


  \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodes}
    \node[degree] (1) at (0,    0/1.5) {1};
    \node[degree] (5) at (2,    7/1.5) {5};
    \node[degree] (8) at (0,   12/1.5) {8};
  \end{pgfonlayer}


  \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
    \draw [line width=5pt,red!20,name path global=mycurve]
    (0,   12/1.5)  to[out=-30,in=90]
    (2,    7/1.5) to[in=57,out=-90]
    (0,    0/1.5);
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  %% Create an intersection coordinate for each l1-l12 lines and mycurve
  %% to place each degree. Each intersection point is named i1 to i12.
  \foreach \i in {1,...,12}{
    \path[name intersections={of={l\i} and mycurve}] (intersection-1) coordinate
    (i\i);
    %%\fill[red] (i\i) circle (2pt);
  }

  \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodes}
    \node[degree] (2) at (i2) {2};
    \node[degree] (3) at (i4) {3};
    \node[degree] (4) at (i5) {4};
    \node[degree] (6) at (i9) {6};
    \node[degree] (7) at (i11) {11};

    %% Draw to arrows supports lines
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3} {
      \draw [red,name path global=mycurve\i]
      ($ (8) + (4-\i,0) $) to[out=-30,in=90]
      ($ (5) + (4-\i,0) $) to[in=57,out=-90]
      ($ (1) + (4-\i,0) $);
    }

  \end{pgfonlayer}

  %% Draw the links
  %%
  %% TODO: find a better way using previously created mycurves 1-3.
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{links}
   \begin{scope}[every path/.append style={shorten <= 2pt}]

    \def\myshift{3}
    \draw[l1,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (i7) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i8) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i9) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i10) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i11) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i12) + (\myshift,0) $)};
    \draw[l1,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (i7) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i6) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i5) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i4) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i3) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i2) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i1) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (1) + (\myshift,0) $)
    };

    \def\myshift{2}
    \draw[l2,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (6) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i10) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (i11) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (8) + (\myshift,0) $)};
    \draw[l2,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (6) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i8) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (5) + (\myshift,0) $)};
    \draw[l2,shorten <= 2pt] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (3) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i3) + (\myshift,0) $)
      ($ (2) + (\myshift,0) $)};

    \def\myshift{1}
    \draw[l3] plot[smooth] coordinates{
      ($ (2) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (i1) + (\myshift,0)$)
      ($ (1) + (\myshift,0) $)
    };
    %% These ones are really not on the mycurves
%     \draw[l3] ($ (7) + (\myshift,0)$) -- ($ (8) + (\myshift,0)$);
%     \draw[l3] ($ (4) + (\myshift,0)$) -- ($ (3) + (\myshift,0)$);
    \draw[l3, intersection segments={of=l2 and mycurve3,sequence=R2}];
    \newcommand{\RedrawSegment}[4][]{
    \ifnum#3>#4
    \path[name path=aux,
     intersection segments={of=l#3 and mycurve#2,sequence=R2}];
     \draw[#1, intersection segments={of=l#4 and aux,sequence=R1}];
    \else
    \path[name path=aux,
     intersection segments={of=l#3 and mycurve#2,sequence=R1}];
     \draw[#1, intersection segments={of=l#4 and aux,sequence={R1}}];
    \fi }
    \RedrawSegment[l3]{3}{5}{4} 
    \RedrawSegment[l3,latex-]{3}{10}{11} 
    %\RedrawSegment[l2]{2}{4}{2} 
    %\RedrawSegment[l2,blue]{2}{9}{7} 
   \end{scope}
  \end{pgfonlayer}

  %% Add extra line helpers for reading
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
    \draw[dashed] (1) -- (8);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i7) + (3,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i7)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i9) + (2,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i9)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i4) + (2,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i4)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i5) + (1,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i5)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i2) + (1,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i2)!(8) $);
    \draw[dashed] ($ (i11) + (1,0) $) -- ($ (1)!(i11)!(8) $);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I did not completely rewrite the code. This has two reasons. One of the reasons is that, in the current way you construct the path, this can lead to `dimension too large` errors. (This is not specific to the redrawing, they would also show up if you were to decorate the paths in the respective region.) The second reason is that I did not understand some of your constructions such as blocks of the type `($ (i7) + (\myshift,0)$)`, which I believe can be made much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Using @marmot's answer works almost.

I easily manage to use the `RedrawSegment` for all paths.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{pgfonlayer}{main}
  %% Create on each degree to intersect later with mycurve.
  %% Each line is a named path from l1 to l12
  \foreach \i in {0,...,12}{
    \coordinate[] (l1-\i) at (0,\i/1.5);
    \coordinate[overlay] (l2-\i) at (10,\i/1.5);
    \path[overlay,name path global=l\i] (l1-\i) -- (l2-\i);
  }
\end{pgfonlayer}

[...]

\begin{pgfonlayer}{links}
   \newcommand{\RedrawSegment}[4][]{%
     \ifnum#3>#4%
     \path[name path=aux,%
       intersection segments={of=l#3 and mycurve#2,sequence=R2}];%
     \draw[#1, intersection segments={of=l#4 and aux,sequence=R1}];%
     \else%
     \path[name path=aux,%
       intersection segments={of=l#3 and mycurve#2,sequence=R1}];%
     \draw[#1, intersection segments={of=l#4 and aux,sequence={R1}}];%
     \fi}%

   %% Shorten on this path does not seem to work correctly.
   \RedrawSegment[l1,latex-,shorten >= 10pt]{1}{12}{7}
   \RedrawSegment[l1,shorten <= 2pt]{1}{7}{0}

   \RedrawSegment[l2,latex-,shorten >= 2pt]{2}{12}{9}
   %% For some reason the arrow on this one is not correctly drawn.  But
   %% if we draw to {6} it works nicely. Maybe because {7} is a junction
   %% point?
   \RedrawSegment[l2,-latex,shorten <= 2pt]{2}{9}{7}
   \RedrawSegment[l2]{2}{4}{2}

   %% No apparent issue on this one
   \RedrawSegment[l3]{3}{5}{4} 
   \RedrawSegment[l3,latex-]{3}{10}{11} 
   \RedrawSegment[l3]{3}{2}{0}
\end{pgfonlayer}
```

The result is way nicer that the plot version. However some issue are still there:

- The arrow from 6 to 5 is not correctly drawn. The path overlaps the arrow tip.
- the arrow from 5 to 8 cannot be shorten.

[image]
[image]